# VS shows fixed exception

Tags: xamlparseexception, visual-studio-mac

I have a simple project with one page which contains default controls.

I made a typo and wrote `Binging` instead of `Binding`.

I got a run-time exception with this typo. I fixed it and restarted the app. But I get the exception with this typo each time in run-time.

I removed `bin` and `obj` folders, cleaned a solution but no luck.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by removing the application from an emulator.